# After meeting with a PI for a postdoc position he asked for my recommendation letters, how should I interpret his later message?

Tags: postdocs

After he received my letters, he wrote to me "I received your letters and I am thinking about this", how long should this take? is this a good sign or a bad sign?

Comment: I'd say nobody asks for rec letters without your chances being reasonably good (personally I do it only if I intend to hire unless there is a giant red flag found). How long does it take? Hard to say.

Comment: He is probably comparing you with other candidates. You also should focus on exploring other opportunities, rather than trying to guess your chances with this one.

Answer (score 1):

He is interested, but probably has other options as well.

If you don't hear in a couple of weeks, send a note asking for a status update and whether you should provide any additional information. Re-express your interest briefly.

Probably not less than a week, nor more than two.

And don't ignore other opportunities that you might have.